# Heat map creation in android studio using google maps api

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I recently created an android app with heat maps using google maps API in android studio. I used below codes for gradient creation. I got a result showing squares? Why I got that result? Need Help Please.

```
int[] colors = {
        Color.GREEN,    // green
        Color.YELLOW,    // yellow
        Color.rgb(255,165,0), //Orange
        Color.RED,              //red
        Color.rgb(153,50,204), //dark orchid
        Color.rgb(165,42,42) //brown
};

float[] startpoints = {
        0.0f,    //0-50
        0.1f,   //51-100
        0.2f,   //101-150
        0.3f,   //151-200
        0.4f,    //201-300
        0.6f      //301-500
};


private ArrayList addheatmap() {
    ArrayList<WeightedLatLng> arr = new ArrayList<>();

    arr.add(new WeightedLatLng(new LatLng(9.9252, 78.119),10)); //madurai
    arr.add(new WeightedLatLng(new LatLng(10.7905, 78.7047),60)); //trichy
    arr.add(new WeightedLatLng(new LatLng(13.0827, 80.2707),180)); //chennai
    arr.add(new WeightedLatLng(new LatLng(11.0168, 76.9558),270)); //coimbatore
    arr.add(new WeightedLatLng(new LatLng(11.7863, 77.8008),380));
    arr.add(new WeightedLatLng(new LatLng(11.7480, 79.7714),190));
    arr.add(new WeightedLatLng(new LatLng(8.7642, 78.1348),299));
    arr.add(new WeightedLatLng(new LatLng(11.6643, 78.1460),398));

    Log.e("adding heatmap","yes");

    return arr;
}


private void buildheatmap(){

    Gradient gradient = new Gradient(colors,startpoints);
    heatmapTileProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
            .weightedData(addheatmap())
            .radius(20)
            .gradient(gradient)
            .build();
    TileOverlayOptions tileoverlayoptions = new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(heatmapTileProvider);
    TileOverlay tileoverlay = googleMap.addTileOverlay(tileoverlayoptions);
    tileoverlay.clearTileCache();
    Toast.makeText(this,"added heatmap",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

[Screenshot of App output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFgz6.png)

I used above colors array and startpoints array for creating gradient for HeatMapTileProvider.
Why I am getting square like structures and what to do to get them in circle like structures? Thank YOU

Answer (score 1):

If you start the startpoints array at 0.05f (or some insignificantly small number) rather than 0 it should get rid of the squareness of the heatmap.